# How to display cursor in UITextField when textfield is not enabled?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I want to display a cursor when the `UITextField` is not property enabled. In my application i have put buttons for the keyboard (A,B,C...). But here i want to display a cursor when I click any alphabets button from a custom keyboard without opening the default iphone keyboard.

Comment: can you post the image how the current keyboard looks like?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578162/custom-keyboard-set-cursor-position????

Comment: [UIView _forgetDependentConstraint:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: Very easy : For Instrument Learning : http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: @autolayout : http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: i Read about links :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [Custom Views for Data Input](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW1) on iOS. Basically you can define a custom keyboard with your own characters and it will wirk the same as the default keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are looking for a `UITextField` with a custom keyboard and show cursor when you press any aphabet. If that is correct......
First Create the class `CustomKeyboard : UIView` and add buttons/layout the view. 
Second for your textfield just set the inputView property to an instance of the class CustomKeyboard `textField.inputView = customKeyboard`;.
Third You'll need to set the `inputView` property to be `readwrite` as well `@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView;` By setting the inputView property, the standard iPhone keyboards will not appear when the textfield becomes first responder.

This way you will get what you are looking for....